# How to stop video auto-play (from linked video) in sharepoint online 2016

Tags: video, sharepoint, autoplay

I've saved some mp4 video files into my document library on SharePoint Online 2016. From there, I've used the video links to added those videos to various pages within my SharePoint site.

However, every time I open a page with a video, the video starts auto-playing.

Is there anyway to stop the auto-playing feature?

Thanks